# How do I show response as string?

Tags: alamofire

I'm using NodeJS as a server:

```
res.send("Hello World")
```

When I try to call this in Alamofire:

```
 AF.request(" ~myIP~ :3000/").response{ response in
                print(response.value!)
            }
```

It returns:

```
Optional(11 bytes)
```

What can I do so that it prints "Hello World" instead of "Optional(19 bytes)"? Thanks 
Also thought I would add that .responseString will make my program not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire has a built in response handler to parse response bodies as `String`s: `responseString`.

```swift
AF.request(...).responseString { response in
    print(response.value ?? "Request failed.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
 AF.request("~myIP~:3000/", method:.get).response{ response in

    let responseString = String(decoding:response.value!!, as: UTF8.self)

    print(responseString)
 }
```